# Getting 500 error on certain pages after server migration

Tags: php, html, sql-server, pdo

I recently migrated Godaddy servers and have run into nothing but problems, all but this have now been solved...

I'm getting a 500 error on my login and signup pages, this is the code from my login page, without this part which updates to the database, the error is not thrown. It never used to happen on the last server, have I used some bad practice here?

PHP Code:

```
$update_stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE users SET last_login = :lastLogin WHERE username = :username");
$update_stmt->bindParam(':username', $uname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$datum = new DateTime();
$lastLogin = $datum->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$update_stmt->bindParam(':lastLogin', $lastLogin, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$update_stmt->execute();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check your logs

Comment: your date, isn't an integer btw, it's a string.

Comment: Thanks, did wonder why I had that there so I changed that, still changed nothing though. Nothing's coming up in the error logs, which logs do you mean?

Comment: a 500 is a server error

Comment: maybe you can see errors using `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Just checked server errors and the line causing a problem is the new DateTime, have I done that correctly?

Comment: along with what's been said using error reporting, use PDO's error handling http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php if you're not already using that, and make sure everything contains value and that the column is of the correct time; namely DATETIME. @Lewis